# PHP email not echoing a foreach loop

Tags: php, email, foreach

I'm trying to send out a php email that lists all of the products the customer ordered. At first I was just listing the variables for the quantity, products, details, etc. It worked, but only one of the products were being included in the email. So I figured a foreach loop was needed. Everything in the email is working except my foreach loop isn't echoing the product details.

This line isn't  echoing...

```
 echo '<p>'.$prdqty.' - '.$prdsize.' - '.$prdname.'</p><br><br>';



$to = $email;
$subject = 'Your Example order';
$message = '<img src="'.$logoImage.'">';
$message .= '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Example Order</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hi '.$billToName.',</p><br><br>
    <p>Thank you for ordering with us!</p>
      <p>Your order was successfully sent to us and we will start processing it immediately.</p><br><br>
      <p>A charge of $'.$total_price.' was placed on '.$billToName.'\'s card that was used for the order.
      <p>Your order contained:</p>';
 foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $id => $product) {
        $product_id = $product['product_id'];
        $prdname =  $products[$product_id]['product_name'];
        $prdprice =  $products[$product_id]['price'];
        $prdqty = $product['quantity'];
        $prdsize = $product['size'];
        echo '<p>'.$prdqty.' - '.$prdsize.' - '.$prdname.'</p><br><br>';                
        }

$message .='

      <p>'.  $AuthorrizeResponseText.';</p><br><br>
      <p>We really appreciate your business!</p>
</body>
</html>
';
$from = "auto-confirm@example.com";
$cc = "order-receipts@example.com";

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: ' .$to. "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' .$from. "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: '.$cc. "\r\n";

// Send the email
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Anyone see anything that would be preventing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace below line into your foreach loop

```
echo '<p>'.$prdqty.' - '.$prdsize.' - '.$prdname.'</p><br><br>';
```

with

```
$message .= '<p>'.$prdqty.' - '.$prdsize.' - '.$prdname.'</p><br><br>';
```

Answer (score 1):

It is echoing, however I think You want to concat products to message, so:

```
echo '<p>'.$prdqty.' - '.$prdsize.' - '.$prdname.'</p><br><br>';
```

Should be:

```
$message .= '<p>'.$prdqty.' - '.$prdsize.' - '.$prdname.'</p><br><br>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
echo '<p>'.$prdqty.' - '.$prdsize.' - '.$prdname.'</p><br><br>';
```

use

```
$message .= '<p>'.$prdqty.' - '.$prdsize.' - '.$prdname.'</p><br><br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not concatenated foreach echo statement in your $message variable

your $message should be something like this

```
$message .= '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Example Order</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hi '.$billToName.',</p><br><br>
    <p>Thank you for ordering with us!</p>
      <p>Your order was successfully sent to us and we will start processing it immediately.</p><br><br>
      <p>A charge of $'.$total_price.' was placed on '.$billToName.'\'s card that was used for the order.
      <p>Your order contained:</p>';
 foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $id => $product) {
        $product_id = $product['product_id'];
        $prdname =  $products[$product_id]['product_name'];
        $prdprice =  $products[$product_id]['price'];
        $prdqty = $product['quantity'];
        $prdsize = $product['size'];
        $message .='<p>'.$prdqty.' - '.$prdsize.' - '.$prdname.'</p><br><br>';               
        }

$message .='

      <p>'.  $AuthorrizeResponseText.';</p><br><br>
      <p>We really appreciate your business!</p>
</body>
</html>
';
```